# iOS screen is constantly refreshed using UIAccessibility voiceover

Tags: ios, uiview, accessibility

I have an iOS app and I want to make it accessible. Everything goes well but in some screens the voice over loses it's focus and jumps to the first accessible element. It's like the screen is always refreshing. I have used UIAccessibilityInspector and I observed that there are ScreenChanged notifications constantly, from time to time. It's really annoying because I don't know why are those notifications sent and how do I stop/control them.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found that it was caused by a UIPageControl and a timer that I set up to automatically cycle the pages in that control. For some reason, the scrolling caused by that was resetting UIAccessibility to the first element in the view, just like you said. Check and see if you have anything animating or changing state.

Comment: Sure, this is the cause, but what is the solution?  Surely you aren't preventing the auto-scrolling now just to avoid the accessibility issue.

Comment: In my case I did use the "UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()" API to check whether VoiceOver was on and turned off the auto-scrolling effect if it was. The user can still manually scroll the scroll view.